# Composer Windows 10 command line issue

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I have a strange problem with running Composer.
When I run any Composer command, it does not clear actual line nad puts lots of status information about reading composer.json.

Maybe is problem in CMD encoding, because text contains some blank squares (Maybe some UTF-8 chars?).

Colors does not work too.

Dos anybody meet similiar problem?

**Image with Composer cmd output**

[image]

Running configuration:

- Windows 10 pro 64bit, version: 1607, Build: 14393.82
- PHP 5.6.16
- Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) - Port defined for Apache: 80

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is an common answer... but can you try it reinstall?

Comment: Yes, it was my first attempt to resolve this.
I try change PHP version to 7 and nothing changes.

I think its more problem of Windows 10 cmd, but my colegues have same settings for command line and they dont have this issue...

Reinstall OS its the last chance for me and I would like avoid it

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue in Windows 10 Anniverssary update which do this. So problem is realy inside cmd.exe and it has nothing to do with Composer.

Temporary solution for me is switch to **Power Shell** or **Bash**. In these two is everything ok.